# Fix Grub Boot Loader after partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, grubrescue

I have a system with dual boot for **Windows 7** and **Ubuntu 12.04**.
The system uses `Grub` as its boot loader.
But, today by mistake, i shrank the Windows Volume and created a new Volume and all worked fine, except when i restarted to discover that boot-loader has gone wrong.
It displays:

```
error: no such partition  
grub rescue>
```

I ran through google and several forums to finally discover many things.
Such as:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Now, i can load back to grub-menu and boot into Ubuntu as well as Windows normally, but by fighting with **grub-rescue** as:

```
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,3)/boot/grub  
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,3)/boot/grub  
grub rescue> insmod normal  
grub rescue> normal
```

Although, this takes to **Grub-menu** for choosing OS, but i want to get away with this.
How, can i fix the **Grub** to get back the screen as earlier? Probably, it requires some resetting in grub, which i can't figure out.
Please provide any method.
**PS:** try to suggest a method, that uses normal user account, as i have to go more for getting `sudo` password.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Pieter. I wasn't able to find that already asked question through search.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reinstall GRUB using a Live system. Since you do not provide the `ls (hd0,X)` output, you should modify as you see fit:

1. In a live session, open the terminal, then type `sudo blkid`. You will get a output similar to this:

   ```
   /dev/sda1: UUID="bf554a2f-a035-4c22-bca8-162def35a03c" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sda2: UUID="3962db06-3776-4f38-8ab9-eab6feeccc1d" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sdb1: UUID="AA64B45A64B42AC9" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sdb2: UUID="F66E431C6E42D551" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sdb3: UUID="75a0854b-8b6b-453f-8aec-2a081a1f19e3" TYPE="swap" 
   /dev/sdb5: UUID="279a18da-130b-46dd-8b54-84da48eb445f" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sdg1: UUID="393cd35e-b827-4dea-acb5-2a66f2369dce" TYPE="ext4"
   ```
2. Here you can see that my Hard Drive is in the `sda` and my pendrive is `sdg`. We are interested in `sda`. Now lest look at the descriptions of the partitions. We want the partitions that are ext4. In my case I have two ext4 partitions. This is because I have my `/boot` separated (which seems to be your case too), I will take note about that, but lets assume that you don't have `/boot` separated for now and that your `/` (root) is `sda1`. Now we will mount sda1.

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
   sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```

   **Tecnical note**: This is the minimum. If you have a `/boot` partition (or any other) separated just mount it the same way, in my case `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot`. Please take note that I used *`/mnt/boot`*, you should change it if using other mount points.
3. Now we will proceed to CHROOTING the partition:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
   ```
4. Now we will proceed to install grub:

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
5. Done. Now reboot in your system. This should add the entries for Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for answer @Braiam. But, i felt using **Boot-rapair** much easier, although it might be doing same steps in the box!